# how can I speak natively when i want to express the meaning of“ turn to the page that is 4 pages back from the last page？

Tags: word-usage

and turn to the page that is in the middle of the book？
These two expressions are ok？

Comment: Assuming the pages are not numbered, which would be the usual way to identify them, you could refer to 'the middle page of the book' and 'the fourth from last page' or 'the page four from the end'.

Comment: Can you write your question more clearly? A little story to explain the background of your question would help, and what it is you are unsure about. Normally, we tell people to turn to a certain page number. Is that what you want to say? Does that work for this book? If not, why not? At the end, ask in a clear question the exact thing you want to know. Clear questions get better answers.

Comment: Those two expressions will prolly be understood but what seems most interesting is why you want to use a structure like "the page that is in the middle of the book."

To me, that suggests you're trying to use literal translation, which will usually be more, and often much more difficult.

Why not use, for instance, "the middle page"?

Similarly, why would you want "the page that is four pages back from the last page…" rather than the simpler "the page four pages back from the last…"?

Comment: seeing your answers to my questions, i find my problem. I can not use english in a very simple way. thanks a lot!

Comment: and in china, people like to refer to the last few pages in this way.  we would prefer to choose the page counted from the end, maybe this is chinese thinking. and english speaker chooses to speak to the page number directly.